# Google Chart how to show values with %

Tags: charts

Hello I want to have a % in my google chart data i have my data like a number but is not accepting %  symbol.

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
data.addRows([
['Line 1', 71.36, 71.36871], 
['line 2', 3.07, 74.44134]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 240,
      title: 'Company Performance'

    };

    var chart = new     
    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {vAxis: {format:'#,#%'} } );
  }
```

I tried puting the data like

```
['Line 1', 71.36,'71.36%'], 
['line 2', 3.07,'3.07%' ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google charts accepts as to give a dictionary with two elements "v" from value and "f" from format.
You can give your values as

```
data.addRows([
['Line 1', {"v":71.36871,"f":"71.36%"}], 
['line 2', {"v":3.07,"f":"3.07%"}]
]);
```